# Wordpress Author Posts Review After Every Change In The Same Wordpress Post

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, admin, author, publish

guys pardon my english,

I am new to wordpress & I have been trying to set up a wordpress website for product reviews where new users will submit their reviews for the product/products. New user who registers on the website will have the role of a 'Author'.

1. User 'XYZ' registers on the website.
2. 'XYZ' wants to add a review of the product.
3. 'XYZ' submits the review.
4. Admin user 'ABC' gets notified via email that the new post has been pending for the    review.
5. 'ABC' approves & publishes the review/post on website.

**Now the problem is that**
XYZ user can again make changes in the same post and can publish them without the approval admin user a.k.a ABC ,because the post have been already approved. This can cause problems.

**What I want to do is**
Every time 'XYZ' user make changes in the post which is already approved, the post should be approved by the admin a.k.a 'ABC' user again.

Comment: You don't come with a lot of information. Wordpress comes with it's inner functionality for handling posts/comments status. They can be 'published', 'pending', 'trash' and so on. You can look [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status) for more information. You can also look [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Comments_in_WordPress) for more information about how to handle comments.

Comment: Please read [ask] and file an [edit].

Comment: ok I'll try to rephrase the question

Comment: I have rephrased the question, is it understandable now